# Obsfuscating C# code

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, reverse-engineering, reflector

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Protect .NET code from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering)
>   [What do you use to protect your .NET code from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106794/what-do-you-use-to-protect-your-net-code-from-reverse-engineering)
>   [How can I protect my .NET assemblies from decompilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478230/how-can-i-protect-my-net-assemblies-from-decompilation)

Given that C# can be reflected and decompiled, can you suggest how I can obsfucate my code or protect it from reverse engineering?