# Is possible to revert an ASP.NET pre-compilation?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a web site, and i'll publish it...

I wanna know if anyone who get access to my FTP and download my pre-compiled website can "revert" the DLL compilation, and re-create my code behinds!

Is it possible?

If it is possible, how can i protect my code?

Comment: If someone unauthorized accesses your FTP, I think that the possibility of a hacker decompiling your binaries would be the least of your concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to [decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-source-code) your assemblies. There's not an 100% safe way to protect you code. You can [obfuscate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrsecurity/archive/2005/05/26/422440.aspx) your assemblies. That will makes it harder, but it's still [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226695/wanted-a-tool-for-decompiling-obfuscated-net-code) to to get your code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes somebody theoretically could, with tools like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). You should try obfuscation of your code.
See: [What do you use to protect your .NET code from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106794/what-do-you-use-to-protect-your-net-code-from-reverse-engineering)

I suggest you try reflector yourself on your own code to see what others could do. It's still a free tool for a few days more...

**EDIT**

Reflector is no longer free (but still a good tool to have!). In alternative there's the free and open-source [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)

Answer (score 2):

If they access your DLL they can open it using reflector and other tools.  You can obfuscate your code to prevent that (actually make it harder, you can't prevent it).

Hide your DLLs well!